# Do you know why the following error is occurring when I try to connect to an Oracle Server "Status : Failure -[LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]"?

Tags: oracle, connection, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

When my colleague attempts to connect he is having no issues. We both have previously been granted access to the server, and have established this is not an issue as my colleague can access the server on my Desktop though I cannot access the server on his desktop. (We both could up until recently when we had had to renew the server connection passwords).

We are both operating off 64-bit, Windows 10 desktops with the same Java version and are both using Oracle SQL Developer 19.2.1.247.

When I go to about properties and compare both in excel we see no differences.

We're quite confused why this is happening.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL or Oracle version 19.2.1.247. Did you mean [Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/uk/tools/downloads/sqldev-v192-downloads.html)? Also, normally we distinguish between a *server* and a *database instance*.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, yes thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: "No such object" sounds like there's a typo somewhere in a database or server name. But people here can't diagnose connectivity issues remotely.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Thanks for looking into the problem. This was one thing that we checked initially. However, there were no problems with this either. We both filled out the connection wizard using the same connection details.

Comment: you can ping the ldap server?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith yes I tried to ping LDAP using telnet hostip 389 on both computers and 636 but neither are connected

Comment: @Tom if you can't reach the ldap server, it's going to be hard to use them to make a database connection - i suggest you talk to a local helpdesk/network administrator

Comment: The tnsnames.ora path was not declared for some reason (Although it certainly was previously). So after updating this path it has worked for myself and some of my colleagues however not for others. I've confirmed that the tnsnames.ora file is coming from the same same path (i.e. $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory) however still the problem persists for some.